# PrimaryKeyField on create and SerialzerField on get

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models. An employee and a manager. When creating an employee, you should supply the ID of the manager (you should never be able to create a new one) and the response should include the manager object. Here's the code

```
class ManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialzier):
    manager = ManagerSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

Right now, it expects to send a Manager object which creates a new manager but it's an ID only field. Upon creation the response should look like this:

```
{
    "id": 90,
    "manager": {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "John"
    }
    ...
}
```

The following throws an exception:

```
POST /employees/

{
    "manager": 10,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Add view where you use the serializers. Not because it is needed but to give you example how to do using your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to achieve this:

1. different fields in serializer
2. different serializers for input and output

My personal preference is number 2.

Examples:

**Using different fields in serializer**

This requires some changes in your cleint side. Basically you use `manager` as read_only field to use on the way out and `manager_id` as write_only field when creating new employee

```
    class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialzier):
        manager = ManagerSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)
        manager_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False,
                                                       allow_null=True,
                                                       write_only=True,
                                                       queryset=Manager.objects.all())                                                                                                     
        class Meta:
            model = Employee
            Fields = ( “manager”, “manager_id”, )

        def validate_manager_id(self, val):
            """ we need to do this because manager_id expects,well, id and not manager object"""
            return val.id if val is not None else None
```

**Using different serializers**

You can create serializer for input and different one for output. And in your view 's `get_serializer_class` you return correct one based on the method (GET / POST).

In this case, you can use same field name `manager` but in one serializer it is ManagerSerializer and in the other one, it can be PrimaryKeyRelatedField ( so it accepts just manager id ).